Why does my computer only start up the second time and after I power it off and then power on?
I have two OS (Linux and Windows) without dual boot. Recently, my computer started not to run after switch it on. But it runs if I power it off, wait for the capacitors to discharge and then power it on.
I tried to change boot priority from Linux to Windows - the same behavior.
I didn't try to disconnect the CMOS battery because I'm afraid break something in the system.
And I didn't try to power off the computer then to hold the power key for 30 seconds and run it again.
Should I try these steps or are there other ways I should try?
SysConf

Linux: Debian 12
Windows: Windows 11
BIOS: F9 (the latest for my motherboard GIGABYTE Z590 UD AC)


"I have two OS (Linux and Windows) without dual boot." How do you switch OS??

I change boot priority in BIOS.

Be sure shutdown of the previous OS is complete. For example, Windows may be in a power state other than G3, i.e., fully shut down (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/power/system-power-states). Enabling Fast Boot or Quick Start in BIOS and in Windows can cause such issues.

It is likely the BIOS drive boot order was at least partially responsible. When you removed the CMOS battery it would have forced the CMOS settings to be defaulted.
Now the system is working it might be worth taking a note of how they are currently set (it may be working but it may not be optimal) - eg. you may want to disable drive bays that are not in use.

Your issue sounds like it could be related to residual charge, a BIOS setting, or possibly a hardware fault. Here are some steps to troubleshoot and potentially fix the issue:
Discharge the System:
Holding the power button for 30 seconds after powering off can help discharge any residual charge that might be causing issues. Here's how to do it:

Power off your computer.
Unplug it from the power source.
Hold the power button for 30 seconds.
Plug it back in and power it on.

Check CMOS Battery:
A weak or failing CMOS battery can sometimes cause boot issues. Replacing the CMOS battery is generally safe and might help if the battery is old. Here’s how to do it:

Power off the computer and unplug it.
Open the computer case.
Locate the CMOS battery (a small coin cell battery on the motherboard).
Carefully remove the old battery and replace it with a new one.
Close the case, plug in the computer, and power it on.

BIOS Settings:
Since you've updated to the latest BIOS, double-check the BIOS settings:

Enter BIOS setup (usually by pressing Delete, F2, or F12 during boot).
Check the boot priority settings.
Ensure that the correct drive is set as the primary boot device.
Save and exit the BIOS setup.

Boot Priority:
You've already changed the boot priority, but ensure it is set correctly for both Linux and Windows.
Hardware Check:
Sometimes, loose connections or failing hardware can cause boot issues:

Ensure all internal cables are securely connected.
Check the RAM sticks and reseat them if necessary.
Make sure the power supply cables are properly connected to the motherboard and other components.

Check for Peripheral Issues:
Disconnect all peripherals (USB devices, external drives, etc.) and try booting again. Sometimes, a faulty peripheral can cause boot issues.
Safe Mode and Logs:
Try booting into Safe Mode for both Windows and Linux to see if it helps. Check system logs for any errors that could provide clues.
For Windows:

Restart the computer and press F8 before the Windows logo appears.
Select Safe Mode from the menu.

For Linux:

Restart the computer and hold Shift during boot to access GRUB.
Select the Linux option and choose recovery mode.

Additional Steps:

Run hardware diagnostics: Many motherboards come with built-in diagnostics tools that can help identify hardware issues.
Check power supply unit (PSU): Ensure that your PSU is functioning correctly and providing stable power to your components.

If none of these seps resolve the issue, it might be worth consulting a professional technician to diagnose potential hardware faults.
It‘s also important to choose the right capacitor. I am currently studying in Shanghai, China. Last week I went to the Shanghai Munich Electronics Show.I collected the top 10 famous capacitor brand in China.

Nippon Chemi-Con Corporation
2.Shanghai Yongming Electronic Co.,Ltd
Nantong Jianghai Capacitor Co., Ltd.
Chongqing Capxon Electronic Industrial Co., Ltd.
Man Yue Technology Holdings Limited
Aihua Group
Xiamen Faratronic Co., Ltd.
Kemet Corporation (China Division)
Guangdong Fenghua Advanced Technology Holding Co., Ltd.
Shenzhen Eyang Technology Development Co., Ltd.

